# Cesium, how to persist baselayer selected by user?

Tags: basemap, cesium

For Cesium, I would like to know how to persist the baselayer selected by user?

For example, if a user selected "Mapbox Streets", how can we detect it was selected and persist it, so that the same "Mapbox Streets" will be used when it is reloaded.

Is there a callback method, so that we know which baselayer the user selected?